# Element type "xs:element" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Having problems with XML Schema.  It is causing a validation error, and I am wondering what the problem is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="row">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="abstract"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="bibliography"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="catno"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="citation"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="copyrightnotice"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description"/ minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="image"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="metadatamodificationdate"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="pagetotal"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="publisher"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="publishercity"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="publishercountry"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="sponsor"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="title"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="titlelargerentity"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:float" name="datemonth"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="datetype"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:float" name="dateyear"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="era"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="language"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="modid"/>
          <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="recordid"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

What is the problem with the `xsd:schema` in the code? Is something missing? It is not validating due to line 2?

Answer (score 3):

This error will arise when **an element declaration is poorly formed**.  Look for characters or keywords that do not belong in an element declaration.

In your case, you have a stray `/` in the declaration of `description`.

Change

```
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="description"/ minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

to

```
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="description" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

and you will eliminate the error.